# UICollectionView within another UIcollectionView

Tags: ios

I am working on UICollectionView, I have an idea to use a collectionView within the cell ?
is it possible

while I am running the project I am getting an error that `"InterFace Builder StoryBoard:
Couldn't compile connection IBCocoa Touch outletConnection  <IBCocoa Touch outletConnection"`

What shall I do now?

can we use two collectionview in one viewcontroller and link to same class

Note:I am using storyboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

You need to hook up delegate and datasource of collectionView inside another Cell correctly to the cell. Check picture:

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer I have tried as u said but I am getting an error like.........."2013-08-01 13:46:37.617 CollectionViewSample[1916:c07] -[Collection collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8da01b0
2013-08-01 13:46:37.620 CollectionViewSample[1916:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Collection collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8da01b0'

Comment: You must implement datasource require method for each CollectionView inside the class which you connect datasource to.